# Log in form not redirecting to new page / registering log in

Tags: javascript, html

Have tried different methods of validating username and password, and sending to the new page but page just reloads after clicking button. Had thought preventDefault() would stop this.
If anyone notices the problem, please let me know, thanks.

```js
const loginForm = document.querySelector('login-form')
const loginButton = document.querySelector('login-form-submit')
loginButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const username = loginForm.username.value;
  const password = loginForm.password.value;
  if (username === 'admin' && password === 'admin1') {
    alert("You have logged in!");
    window.open('Data.html');
  } else {
    alert("Incorrect Password");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="signin">
  <form id="login-form">
    Sign in to access your account
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="name">Account Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username-field" name="username" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Username"><br><br>
    <label for="password">Account Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password-field" name="password" class="login-form-field" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="login-form-submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good approach to validate passwords clientside, it's better to do it server side. If you have no backend at the moment you could even do it with .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do is to use `input type="button"`, just change from `submit` to `button`

```
<input type="button" value="Log In" id="login-form-submit" />
```

Also, you have an error in your d`ocument.querySelector`. To get element by id, you need to use `#` like

```
document.querySelector('#login-form-submit')
```

Comment: Still refreshes on submit unfortunately

Comment: That's because you have missed # in your query selector, I have updated the answer as well

Comment: Did not know that. Solved my problem completely. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const username = e.currentTarget.querySelector('[name="username"]').value;
    const password = e.currentTarget.querySelector('[name="password"]').value;
})
```

Comment: Still just refreshes on submit unfortunately

Comment: @scottmcn do you have several elements on your page with an id / classname "login-form"?